# How to get batch of Users by some field and with numbering like without field?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

For example. We have 300 Users with numeric field "score" and boolean field "isLogged".
I can set to each User his number by field "score" like this (pseudocode)

```
query(Parse.User)
.OrderByDescending("score")
.forEach(function(user, index){
user["index_number"]=index;
});
```

So now we have 300 numbered by "score" users. If we have too much users, for example 300000, I can request only 80 users. I just say - gimme 80 users with center at 300, and then it gives me users from 260 to 340.

```
 function(center){
    query(Parse.User)
    .OrderByDescending("score")
    .Skip(center-40)
    .Limit(80)
    .forEach(function(user, index){
    user["index_number"]=index+center-40;
    });
 }
```

and it gives me 80 numbered users.

But what, if I want get 80 users where field "isLogged"==true, and these users must have right numbering?
I see only one solution - numbering of all 300000 users and then take 80 users that have field "islogged"==true but already without numbering. But it looks too expensive.

Is there more optimal solution?

Comment: Why don't you try what you're aiming for in real code.  Post it here if it doesn't work.

Comment: ehm, your know, the problem is not in code, the problem in idea

Comment: Code would help me understand the question... After rereading, I think I get it. The question is how to assign a sequence number to query results that are made discontiguous by the bool criterion. Answer is either (a) do it on beforeSave or (b) naturally the only way to know how far to advance the counter is to have found the intervening rows. Query them in unqualified blocks.

Comment: What is "the intervening rows"? (a) is not suitable because BOOL field can change

Comment: Intervening = the rows that would have been found if you didn't qualify the query. The reason this is a problem is that index as you've defined it isn't a property of the object, but a property of the query result. Maybe you can explain why you need this?

Comment: There is a leaderboard, and I have few tabs, first tab - is Global tab, this tab shows batch of users that ranked by score. Also there is a Local tab that must shows users ranked by score but only from some specified country.

Comment: Ah... the last comment is well stated.  I think OP would be improved by that restatement.

Answer (score 0):

The approach for leaderboards is to sort a query by some score field and present the results to the user.  There's isn't a need to *assign* because that property is particular to the query that found the object (both temporally and logically).

So the all-world leaderboard query is about what you suggest:

```
function worldLeaders(skip, limit) {
    PFQuery worldLeader = new Parse.Query("GamePlayed");
    worldLeader.descending("score");
    worldLeader.skip = skip;
    worldLeader.limit = limit;
    return worldLeader.find().then(function(gamesPlayed) {
        for (i = 0; i < gamesPlayed.length; i++) {
            var gamePlayed = gamesPlayed[i];
            var rank = skip + i;  // consider adding 1 to rank, since people prefer natural numbers
            console.log("the rank is " + rank + " for record " + JSON.stringify(gamePlayed));
        }
    });
}
```

The UI would call this with skip=0, then, as the user pages, skip=limit, limit*2, etc. and present "rank" as shown for the results.  There's no reason to assign that rank to the objects... in fact there's good reason not to.

Qualified leaders would work the same way, just qualified...

```
function frenchLeaders(skip, limit) {
    PFQuery frenchLeader = new Parse.Query("GamePlayed");
    frenchLeader.equalTo("country", "France");
    frenchLeader.descending("score");
    frenchLeader.skip = skip;
    frenchLeader.limit = limit;
    return frenchLeader.find().then(function(gamesPlayed) {
        for (i = 0; i < gamesPlayed.length; i++) {
            var gamePlayed = gamesPlayed[i];
            var rank = skip + i;  // consider adding 1 to rank, since people prefer natural numbers
            console.log("the rank is " + rank + " for record " + JSON.stringify(gamePlayed));
        }
    });
}
```

Results from each are presented on each tab.  The UI's job is to remember the skip for the current page and associate (visually) the rank as computed with the records.

But what about the world rank of the French players?  To get the rank, call the matching query, and then filter locally...

```
// present French users along with their world-level rank
var skip = 0;   // let the user set this with the UI
worldLeaders(skip, 100).then(function(gamesPlayed) {
    console.log("the top french players are:");
    for (i=0; i<gamesPlayed.count; i++) {
        var gamePlayed = gamesPlayed[i];
        var rank = skip + i;

        // lets say that GamePlayed has a pointer to user, and the query does a .include("user")
        var user = gamePlayed.get("user");
        if (user.get("country") == "France") {
            console.log("the world rank of this french player is " + rank + " for record " + JSON.stringify(gamePlayed));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Will users in second function have continuously ranks? I mean skip+0, skip+1, skip+2... skip+80 ?

Comment: Yes, for sure.  It's computed in the for loop as a function of that continuous counter.   Called with skip=0, it will be 0,1,2... called with skip=100, it will be 100,101,102...

Comment: That is a problem. Ranks must be like in not qualified query, but objects must be like in qualified query

Comment: To get the word rank of the french player?  I see.  Sure.  Please see edit.

Comment: I see. So at first we get 100 users from any country, and then take only users with country=="France". But what if there is no users from France, between skip and center. I meant, we have center at 300, and we try to get 100 users, so skip will be 250 and limit is 100. But if between 250 and 300 there is no users from France, but these users are lower then 250, then we have to get needed users that lower then 250. How to do it? Number of users is important.

Comment: Sorry, got distracted a bit this am.  I see your point.  To get what you're going for (you'd have the app cursor through the data, setting skip to the length of the last result) until it has collected enough records.